# How to access individual values of a struct?

Tags: json, swift

I'm trying to print the individual members of Results after parsing JSON data and assigning it to Question.

```
struct Question: Decodable
{
    let response_code: Int
    let results: [Results]
}

struct Results: Decodable
{
    let category: String
    let question: String
    let correct_answer: String
    let incorrect_answers: [String]   
}
```

I tried using:

```
print(question.results)
```

But I get:

```
[Trivia_Game.Results(category: "Entertainment: Music", question: "Which of the following bands is Tom DeLonge not a part of?", correct_answer: "+44", incorrect_answers: ["Box Car Racer", "Blink-182", "Angels &amp; Airwaves"])]
```

How do I access the individual members such as "category" or "question"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to first access an individual element of `question.results`, like so:

```
question.results[n] // where n represents a valid array index number
```

And then to access specific properties of that individual `Results` structure, you would do it in the same way as you would access the value of a property of any other struct. For example, if you wanted to get the value of the `category` member of a `Results` structure, you would do this:

```
question.results[n].category
```

And then if you wanted to *print* the value of that specific member (again, using the `category` member as an example), you would do this:

```
print(question.results[n].category)
```

Now, if you wanted to print out the value of the `category` member for each of the `Results` structures in the `question.results` array, then you could use a for loop like so:

```
for result in question.results {
    print(result.category)
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank-you. Quick follow up question, I'm trying to access the elements outside of the URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url). I created a variable outside and attempted to pass it in but that doesn't work.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand exactly what you mean, although I have a very limited knowledge on working with JSON in Swift, so I may not be the best person to ask. Perhaps something on one of these links could help you: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession/1411554-datatask or https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession

Comment: Thank-you! Figured it out.

Comment: Great! Glad to hear that.

Answer (score 1):

`results` is an array. You have to enumerate the array

```
let results = question.results
for result in results {
    print(result.category, result.question)
}
```

or

```
question.results.forEach { print($0.category, $0.question) }
```

Comment: Thank-you. Quick follow up question, I'm trying to access the elements outside of the URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url). I created a variable outside and attempted to pass it in but that doesn't work.

Comment: `dataTask(with: url)` works asynchronously. The completion block is returned later.

Comment: Oh okay. I was able to figure it out. Thank-you!